# How to update magento from 2.1.1 to 2.2

Tags: magento-2.1

I have a magento version 2.1.1 but I have a few bugs in this version. I hope that upgrading to magento 2.2 will fix these problems.

Can anyone help me how I can update so that I do not lose my data?

Comment: http://inchoo.net/magento-2/update-magento-2-installation/

Comment: https://support.cloudways.com/how-to-upgrade-magento-2-via-cli/

Comment: Always google/research first my friend :-)